# Why are photos from telescope stretched at their edges?

Tags: telescope, image-processing

You may know the issue that photos from (at least some) telescopes are stretched at the edges, so that the star locations do not fit compared to if this location would be on the center of the photo.

Why is this happening? I am looking for a detailed geometrical explanation

Is there a standard way to describe this shift? In a YouTube video about Astropy, it said that the shift is proportional to a quadratic polynomial.

Is there a common way to handle this issue?

Comment: Do you have an example? It sounds to me like it's simply for the same reason that a map of Earth is "stretched" toward the poles: You're trying to map a spherical coordinate system onto a flat surface, which can never be more than an approximation. The larger the field of view you have, the larger the effect you'll see.

Comment: It'd be a really good idea to provide an example of the type of distortion you're interested in.

Comment: What Pela said. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection

Comment: so do you mean that a telescope image is stereographic projection, it is then polynom of grade 2 not 4

Comment: No, a photo is a perspective projection, with various optical distortions mentioned by planetmaker. But mapping the celestial sphere to a flat image requires some kind of map projection. The stereographic projection is one of the easiest projections to understand (and it preserves angles).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a general property of optics. In what way an image is distorted depends on the exact optical setup and will need careful calibration. Usually the best imaging quality is found in the center of an image and the edges becoming more subject to various typical imaging errors.

The most prominent one is [distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(optics)). EO sell optics but do a good job at [explaining it](https://www.edmundoptics.eu/knowledge-center/application-notes/imaging/distortion/), too (no, I'm not affiliated). This effect can be approximated by a 4th order polynomial as it is symmetric to the center of the image, the coefficients are specific to your setup.

Besides distortion there are various types of [optical aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_aberration) for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The primary challenges of telescope design are keeping good focus<sup>1</sup> across a locally flat<sup>2</sup> focal plane, meeting aperture and field of view targets while using the *fewest optical elements.*

Now most designs that do that with a few optical elements have substantial [field distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(optics)).

For small optical systems like camera lenses (see below) you add more lenses with more optical surfaces and therefore more degrees of freedom to your design.

We expect a camera to take an incoming light field and project it on to our CCD or film very similarly to how a [pinhole camera](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pinhole-camera.svg) would [project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane) it.

So these days even the tiny camera in a high-end smart phone can have as many as a half-dozen optical elements!

Because of gravity<sup>3</sup> reflective losses and other degradations at each surface, reflecting telescopes are preferred with as few elements as possible.

Since the data has to go through substantial processing and computer analysis and doesn't need to go strait to snapchat, nobody cares if there's some field distortion. It can be well characterized and corrections can be applied automatically.

- <sup>1</sup>near-[diffraction-limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system)-[point spread function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function)
- <sup>2</sup>some focal planes are tiled with CCDs tilted at slightly different angles, but each CCD is flat over at least several centimeters.
- <sup>3</sup>heavy telescope elements on Earth deform under gravity, and are expensive/difficult to put into space.

---

[image]

**above:** [Transiting Exoplanet Survey Satellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transiting_Exoplanet_Survey_Satellite) (TESS) camera from Spaceflight 101's [TESS Instrument Overview](https://spaceflight101.com/tess/tess-instrument/)

**note:** Probably TESS' lens is complicated primarily to achieve diffraction-limited achromatic performance over its full field of view rather than to have zero distortion, but right now I can't say for sure.

**below:**  from Vladan Blahnik & Oliver Schindelbeck's [Smartphone imaging technology and its applications](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/aot-2021-0023/html)

[image]